# How to patch a java library?

Tags: java, batik

I am willing to change a method inside a Java library.
I cannot extend the class for casting reason. 
I wish to override

```
@Override
public void interrupt() {...}
```

of class

```
org.apache.batik.bridge.UpdateManager
```

The patch is here:
[Interrupts the manager tasks.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12556752/UpdateManager.txt)

Comment: I think you need to rebuild the library from source..

Comment: you can create the same package `org.apache.batik.bridge.UpdateManager
` in your project and copy the class and change where ever you want

Comment: What is "casting reason"?

Comment: Looking at that patch, it should be proposed to the batik project. However, looking by the age of that patch, perhaps its not maintained anymore - maybe you should just fork the software?

Comment: The casting reason is that JSVGCanvas.getUpdateManager() returns UpdateManager. So I am stuck with it. The patch is necessary due to a issue in this library. I need to change change the interrupt() method.

Comment: Also I do not find the code for org.apache.batik.bridge.UpdateManager, if any one knows where to find it, I would rebuilt the library as proposed here.

Comment: You could use the one of the decorator, facade or adapter design patterns.

Comment: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/batik/bridge/UpdateManager.java.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not good practice but you can create same package in your project `org.apache.batik.bridge.UpdateManager` then copy the whole class in it and change the parts you want. When you build the project your class will use instead of `org.apache.batik.bridge.UpdateManager`. But It's not good practice to do it because the code maintenance is hard and whenever you update the library you should check and update your custom class.

Comment: Note: Just make sure that your update has precedence on the classpath.

Comment: I found the code here : https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.xmlgraphics/batik-bridge/1.8/source-code/org/apache/batik/bridge/UpdateManager.java and modified the source with https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12556752/UpdateManager.txt

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for Android? Gradle tells me Type foo.bar.Baz is defined multiple times. Any way around this?